# Leave-one-out cross-validation [fbprophet]

Tags: python, facebook-prophet

I have a training-set `Xtrain` consisting of two years of data and `Xtest` consisting of 1 year of data.

I would like to create a rolling "leave-one-out" to simulate how the model performs on a day-to-day predictio i.e use `Xtrain` to predict the first observation in `Xtest`, then add the first observation of `Xtest` to `Xtrain` for predicting the second observation of `Xtest` etc.

I thought about using the `cross_validation` module of `fbprophet` with

```py
model.fit(pd.concat((X_train,X_test)))

df_cv = cross_validation(model,cutoffs=X_test["ds"],horizon = '1 day')
```

but I get the error

`ValueError: Dataframe has no rows.`